# How do I run rake db:migrate in automated deploy with heroku or heroku-api gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku

I'm using this in a rake task:

```
client = Heroku::Client.new('', 'heroku-api-key')
client.rake 'my-app-name', 'db:migrate'
```

and all I get is

RestClient::UnprocessableEntity: 422 Unprocessable Entity.

Other commands work, such as

```
client.ps('my-app-name')
```

The heroku client.rb uses

```
rake(app_name, cmd)
```

so I'm not sure what is wrong. I can't see a way to debug the response, even when using RESTCLIENT_LOG=stdout.

Comment: I've always just done `heroku run rake db:migrate`; does that not work for you, or is there some other reason you're trying to do this using `Heroku::Client`? (Honest question—I know basically nothing about that library.)

Comment: Do you have SSL enabled on the project?

Comment: It is being run as part of an automated deploy from Travis, so I have the Heroku API key, but I wasn't intending to put the full Heroku credentials into my git repository. That's why I can't use the normal `heroku run rake` approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you export your API key, you can run the heroku command line without needing to script the API:

```
export HEROKU_API_KEY=<your key>
heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

A little too late but try this if you have not figured it out.

`heroku run bash` and then

`rake db:migrate` as you would do it on your local machine